# Need help structuring php script for twilio callend.php

Tags: php, html, twilio

I'm having trouble creating a "Click Here" html element in my twilio callend.php email confirmation.  I need assistance with proper structure.

This is what I'm using.  the echo "Click here, section is causing the email send to fail.

```
<?php
$recording = $_REQUEST["RecordingUrl"];

$email = "twilio@realaccesspro.com,frank@realaccesspro.com,chuck.ward@realaccesspro.com";
$from = $_REQUEST['From'];

$subject = "You Have a New Call Capture Lead " . $from;

if(strtolower($_REQUEST['TranscriptionStatus']) == "completed") {
    // email message with the text of the transcription and a link to the audio recording
    $body = "You have a new voicemail from " . $from . "\n\n";
    $body .= "Text of the transcribed voicemail:\n{$_REQUEST['TranscriptionText']}.\n\n";
    $body .= "Click this link to listen to the message:\n{$_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']}.mp3";
} else {        
    // transcription failed so just email message with just a link to the audio recording
    $body = "You have a new voicemail from " .$from . "\n\n";
    $body .= echo "<a href="{$_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']}.mp3">Click here to listen to the message:</a>\n";
    }
mail($email, $subject, $body);
?>
```

How can I mask the URL that usually displays in the emails my server sends with a simple "Click Here".  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's **echo** returns **void**. It looks like your outputting that string and concatenating **void** to the **$body** variable. Try removing **echo**.

Also, escape the quotes (\") for the **href**.